# Apple Research kit example Asthma app doesn't run properly

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

I am trying out Apple research kit example Asthma, which I am able to run in emulator but i am not able to go past the tasks screen, it shows available tasks but doesn't load any questions based on it, i tried tracing code but its huge, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/ResearchKit/AsthmaHealth/issues/8

Someone is working on a fix now, finger crossed.

Comment: there is another bug , when you run the app on iPad it doesn't go beyond registration screen , unlike iPhone app, i have built it as a universal app can you please look into this ?

Comment: Although *ResearchKit* has iPad supports, unfortunately there are [no plans add iPad support the current example apps](https://github.com/ResearchKit/AsthmaHealth/issues/10).